# How to disable pointer-events on web component with polymer?

Tags: polymer, pointer-events

How do I set temporarily disable/enable a `pointer-event` in polymer web component by setting css properties `pointer-events: none` and `pointer-events: auto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the element's `pointer-events` style [programmatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information#Modify_an_element_style). For example:

```
this.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
setTimeout(() => {
  this.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
}, 4000);
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ypdmdx?editors=1011)